# Can Alfresco Explorer and Alfresco Share be configured to use different authentication chains?

Tags: alfresco

Right now I have Alfresco setup with this authentication chain:

```
authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm,ldap1:ldap
```

However, it would be nice if I could use that for Alfresco Share, and this for Alfresco Explorer:

```
authentication.chain=alfinst:alfrescoNtlm
```

Is there a way to configure these applications to use different authentication chains? If not, can this be done through an extension of some sort?

Comment: I'm not sure why you'd want to have Share and Explorer using different chains, since they can both access the same content in the repo. Maybe you could edit your question to include some info on why you want to do it?

Comment: Based on my company's rules, any application exposed to users has to have certain customizations made. Our plan is to only provide users access to Share, and have Explorer be available only to admins. We basically want to avoid customizations and maintenance of those customizations to Explorer. We could possibly rewrite incoming URLs, but I figured I'd see if it was easy to have the two applications use differing authentication chains.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Explorer and Web Scripts URLs make use of [different authentication filters](http://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/web-client/source/web/WEB-INF/web.xml), therefore it's possible for you to hook in your customized selective authentication handling. Beware: AFAICS this is not a completely supported use case, you might therefore end up [re]writing more code than you wanted. You've been warned, HBD.

A possible approach might be:

- having a custom filter mapped on the Explorer URLs that sets a `AUTH_WEB_CLIENT` session attribute
- customizing the LDAP authentication component to check whether such a session attribute is set, and skip authentication if so

Answer (score 0):

@Skuro was nice enough to provide some nice ways to do it. Personally I'm more inclined to your own proposal, particularly if you have Apache in front of Alfresco (which is a nice-to-have, anyway). Your proposal "We could possibly rewrite incoming URLs..." seem to be good way idea. That way you don't have to touch your Alfresco chaining configuration, which can be a bit more complex, so it is easier to mess up things.